# Complex math symbols, and definitions

Tags: notation

I find it difficult to explain this because I'm not sure what is the correct term to use.  Symbols such as the triple-bar-equal sign, and a few other symbols that I find difficult to describe.  I was wondering if there was a list of symbols with definitions.

Comment: Here should find plenty of stuff for indulging in "recreational mathematics" :) http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/LaTeX:Symbols

Comment: I replaced the (recreational-mathematics) tag by the slightly more appropriate (notation) tag. If anyone can think of a better tag to use, please change that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at Wikipedia's [table of mathematical symbols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_mathematical_symbols).

Comment: I was searching for such a reference. Thanks !